# Подключение к БД Oracle (ORA-12514)

Tags: php, oracle

При попытке подключения к удаленному серверу через oci_connect появляется ошибка:
    ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor.       Параметры для подключения брала из tnsnames.ora, и через Toad соединение с этой базой с данными параметрами работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что может быть не так и как это исправить?  Параметры для подключения выглядят примерно таким образом:

```
 (DESCRIPTION =  
      ( ADDRESS =   
          (PROTOCOL = TCP)  
          (HOST = 180.180.180.180)  
          (PORT = 1521)  
      )  
      (CONNECT_DATA =  
       (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL)  
    )  
)
```

Comment: Думаю, будет полезно показать код PHP

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было вместо SERVICE_NAME определить SID.

Comment: SERVICE_NAME было правильно, надо было только имя базы указать. SID тоже может работать, но это устаревшая деректива.